# recommended computer monitor brightness, contrast and gamma settings for eyes?

Tags: display, desktop-computer, brightness, contrast, gamma

I'm a software developer. I'm working up to 10 hours per day in computer.

```
How to properly adjust monitor brightness and contrast.
```

Comment: http://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/how-to-calibrate-your-monitor/ read this article.  10 hours is not too much. I am working  approx 16-17 hour in a day.

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/54872/how-to-avoid-computer-eye-strain-and-keep-your-eyes-healthy/ Rest your eyes.